# How to perform click event with tags in C#

Tags: button, tags, click, using

I have been developing a game like Minesweeper and generate buttons with code. The buttons have tags (two-dimensional array, for x and y axis). When I click a button I count mines around that button and wanna click the number is zero. In sum, how can i perform the click events of the buttons with their tags? (Starting from a button that generated with code and has only tag and name)

Here is how i generated the buttons:

```
for (int i = 0; i < genişlik; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < yükseklik; j++)
            {

                Button btn = new Button();
                btn.Width = 30;
                btn.Height = 30;
                btn.Left = i * 30;
                btn.Top = j * 30;
                btn.Text = "";
                btn.Tag = new int[] { i, j };



                this.Controls.Add(btn);
             }
         }
```

Comment: how you will store info when behind that button is a mine?

Comment: I created a two-dimensional int array and all of the values are 0(not a mine) at the beginning. Then make some of their values 1(that means it's a mine).(or course randomly) Finally i compare the buttons tags and array elements values if its 0 or 1. Is it clear?

Answer (score 0):

You simply use:

```
btn.Click += method();

       private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```